# Endless loop in useState call when trying to render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

Hey I have a problem with a loop with my useState functions when I try to write tests for it. In the tests I use

```
renderWithProviders(
            <HistoryRouter history={memoryHistory}>
                <Detail />
            </HistoryRouter>
        )
```

This causes an infinite loop in which the test doesn't finish.

Following is the Detail component which is being rendered by the test above:

```
export const Detail: React.FC = () => {
const [selectData, setSelectData] = useState<any | undefined>([])

const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>()
const { data: new } = useQuery(['detail', id], async () => {
    return someApi.get({ id: id as string })
})

// some code here

 const { data: someByStatus } = useQuery(
    ['someList', id, status],
    async () => {
        return status
            ? await someApi.getSome({
                  id: id as string,
                  status,
              })
            : await someApi.getSome({
                  id: id as string,
              })
    }
)

return (
    <React.Fragment>
         
//some code here

            <Box>
                <MyList
                    status={status}
                    updateSelectData={setSelectData}
                    someData={someByStatus}
                />
            </Box>

//some code here

    </React.Fragment>
)
}
```

Following is the MyList, which is being called by the Detail component. The loop is properly happening at the updateSelectData(filteredStatus).

```
export const MyList: React.FC<MyListProps> = ({
status,
updateSelectData,
someData,
}) => {


useEffect(() => {
    if (!status && someData) {
        let filteredStatus: SomeEnum[] = []
        
        // some logic here...

        // loop is happening here at this updateSelectData call
        updateSelectData(filteredStatus)
    }
 
}, [someData, status, updateSelectData])
```

Any idea how to fix this loop? It really only happens when I try to render it for test purposes. If I render it in the browser, no loop is being triggered or its not noticeable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

UseEffect cause too many re renders if we call `setSomething` in call back and put `something` in change list.

Its not possible to have useEffect based on `[someData, status, updateSelectData]` since change in `someData` triggers the `useEffect` callback which calls `updateSelectData` which is again changing state `SomeData` in parent component. This is a recursion.

If you want change in someData, set it explicitly on in parent component.

Comment: Isn't someData already getting set in the parent component (in Detail) or what do you exactly mean with "set it explicitly on in parent component"?

Comment: I mean you should set the state someData outside useEffect that depends on someData.

Comment: But isn't someData already getting set outside of useEffect with the useQuery call? Or is it possible to access someData in another way for my if clause?

Comment: your `updateSelectData(filteredStatus)` eventually cause change in someData. No matter it's inside or outside. This is not acceptable for useEffect ussage.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand what I would then need to do to solve the loop without removing someData from the logic of myList component. Do you mean moving the whole logic into the Detail component?